Passing multiple parameters to bicepparam from azure devops pipeline
We have a main.bicep file which takes in multiple parameters from azure devops pipeline. The values of the parameters change according the environment where we are deploying.
We call this file from azure-pipelines.yml file as az deployment group validate --template-file main.bicep --parameters main.bicepparam. Since this file takes multiple parameters, I don't want to pass --parameters key=value multiple times. I don't want to hard-code the values in the .bicepparam file as the value can change according to the environment.
Is there a better way to do it? I thought of creating a .bicepparam file for each environment but that involves duplication of parameters in all the files

--parameters key=value is not a bad option if there aren't that many custom parameters per environment. Other options such as for example using a custom task to replace tokens require extra work.

Hi @rakesh, Have you got a chance to check the suggestion in the comments and answer below? The override parameter feature is limited by ARM template use and may not be optimized by Azure DevOps. Hope the information can solve your concerns. Thx.

hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT , we are already using --parameter value1 in our deployment multiple time but we want to avoid it. Below solution also suggests to use --parameter multiple times. So we thought of using parameters.json instead of .bicep and that we dont need to pass --parameter multiple times. We are using file transform task which takes care of converting parameters in json file to actual values.

Hi @rakesh, thanks for the update. The suggested task AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 in the answer below supports parameters.json template as well. Hope the information helps. Thx.

Answering my solution here since we didnt want to use multiple --parameter option.
We are using the readEnvironmentVariable function in .bicepparam file and the values are set in azure pipelines. So that we can directly read them from .bicepparam file and we dont need to pass multiple --parameter option.

You may use AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 task. Additionally, it is explained here: Deploy Bicep files - Use Azure Resource Manager Template Deployment task. Use csmFile for your bicep file, csmParametersFile for main.bicepparam, and overrideParameters to assign new values for your parameters in the following format:
overrideParameters: -parameter_name1 value1 -parameter_name2 $(value2_from_pipeline_variables)

